# Threads: Why must all user threads be mapped to a kernel thread?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, operating-system

So two questions here really. First, (and yes, I have searched this already, but wanted clarification), what is the difference between a user thread and a kernel thread? Is it simply that one is generated by a user program and the other by an OS, with the latter having access to privileged instructions? Are they conceptually the same or are there actual differences in the threads themselves?

Second, and the real problem of my question is: the book I am using says that "a relationship must exist between user threads and kernel threads," going on to list the different models of such a relationship. But the book fails to clearly explain **why** a user thread **must always** be mapped to a specific kernel thread. Why is this?

Comment: Great question. And the book is "Operating System Concepts" by Abraham Silberschatz and others.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A *kernel thread* is a thread object maintained by the operating system. It is an actual thread that is capable of being scheduled and executed by the processor. Typically, kernel threads are heavyweight objects with permissions settings, priorities, etc. The kernel thread scheduler is in charge of scheduling kernel threads.

User programs can make their own thread schedulers too. They can make their own "threads" and simulate context-switches to switch between them.  However, these threads aren't kernel threads.  Each user thread can't actually run on its own, and the only way for a user thread to run is if a kernel thread is actually told to execute the code contained in a user thread.  That said, user threads have major advantages over kernel threads.  They can be a lot more lightweight, since they don't necessarily need to have their own priorities, can be managed by a single process (which might have better info about what threads need to run when), and don't create lots of kernel objects for purposes of security and locking.

The reason that user threads have to be associated with kernel threads is that by itself a user thread is just a bunch of data in a user program. Kernel threads are the real threads in the system, so for a user thread to make progress the user program has to have its scheduler take a user thread and then run it on a kernel thread.  The mapping between user threads and kernel threads doesn't have to be one-to-one (1 : 1); you can have multiple user threads share the same kernel thread (only one of those user threads runs at a time), and you can have a single user thread which is rotated across different kernel threads in a 1 : n mapping.

Answer (score 9):

I think a real world example will clear the confusion, so let’s see how things are done in Linux.

First of all Linux doesn’t differentiate between process and thread, entity that can be scheduled is called task in Linux and represented by `task_struct`. So whenever you execute a `fork()` system call, a new `task_struct` is created which holds data (or pointer) associated with new task.

### So in Linux world a kernel thread means a `task_struct` object.

Because scheduler only knows about these entities which can be assigned to different CPU’s (logical or physical). In other words if you want Linux scheduler to schedule your process you must create a `task_struct`.

User thread is something that is supported and managed outside of kernel by some **execution environment (EE from now on)** such as JVM. These EE’s will provide you with some functions to create new threads.

### But why a user thread must always be mapped to a specific kernel thread.

Let’s say you created some threads using your EE. eventually they must be executed by the CPU and from above explanation we know that the thread must have a `task_struct` in order to be assigned to some CPU. That is why the mapping must exist. It’s the duty of your EE to create `task_structs`.

If your EE uses many to one model then it will create only one `task_struct` for all the threads and it will schedule all these threads onto that `task_struct`. Think of it as there is one CPU (`task_struct`) and many processes (threads created in EE), your operating system (the EE) will multiplex these processes on that single CPU.

If it uses one to one model than there will be one `task_struct` for every thread created in EE. So when you create a new thread in your EE, corresponding `task_struct` gets created in the kernel.

Windows does things differentlly ( process and thread is different ) but general idea stays the same that is kernel thread is the entity that CPU scheduler considers for assignment hence user threads must be mapped to corresponding kernel threads (if you want CPU to execute them).